# Laravel 4 No tests found in TestCase

Tags: phpunit, testcase

I'm having some problems with phpunit. When I execute a test, phpunit give me these warnings:

> 1) Warning
>   No tests found in class "Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase".
>
> 2) Warning
>   No tests found in class "TestCase".

But I'd like to **ignore** these files, so that phpunit won't try to run tests from them.

How to do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Hopefully by now you found the answer but if you haven't this might help:

> Hmm - make sure that the filenames and class names all match up. For
> example, no FooTest class with a filename of BarTest.php.
>
> Also, are you positive that you have a *Test.php file within the
> app/tests directory?
>
> [...]
>
> That was it, i.e. one of my tests had a typo in the filename-vs-classname. Odd that typo kicks a warning in the TestCase classes and instead of flagging the class that actually caused it.

From:
https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=83-warnings-for-testcase-illuminate-foundation-testing-testcase/0

Basically, make sure your file names and class names match up. I was banging my head on this one too.

Comment: May also happen if testcase (method) does not begin with the work test.

Comment: Link is dead (which is why links in SO answers are a bad idea).

Comment: Quick tip: make the base class (in this case it's called TestCase) an abstract class.

Comment: the question is actually how to **not** have these files evaluated, whereas you're answering how to **make sure** they are...

Answer (score 47):

An additional solution could be to make the TestCase class abstract. By doing so, PHPUnit will not try to find any tests in it.

`abstract class TestCase {`

Comment: Saved me too. PHPunit was complaining about tests in base class in which enviroment was set up

Comment: this is the real answer.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the problem was that the class name did not match the file name, so a class defined as

```
class ExampleTest {
```

was not named ExampleTest.php.

If there are certain test files you would want to ignore, then go into the phpunit.xml file and inside

```
<testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
    <directory></directory>
</testsuite>
```

replace the directory tags with  tags and specify the specific test file you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a convention mistake. The solution was changing the class name, and file, from `TestFoo` to `FooTest`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. I've checked that my file name and class name were the same as `AuthTest.php` and `AuthTest` respectively.

But still I was getting the same warning maybe because I've renamed the `ExampleTest.php` to `AuthTest.php`.

Anyways I've deleted the previous file and used the `php artisan make:test AuthTest` 
and it worked.